# Check if dev dependencies are used in production code

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, production-environment

The problem: in one class, I accidentally (IDE autocomplete) used

`use Composer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;`

instead of

`use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;`

and since I have the former class on my dev environment, the code worked fine, the tests worked fine, etc. Furthermore, Jenkins build for live environment also ran successfully. I only found out about error the hard way: on live website. That's because fatal error is only thrown when the class that has a bad `use` is actually accessed.

I know that I could run `composer install --no-dev` and then test the code locally but that adds some overhead.

Maybe there is some automated tool that I could use in Jenkins build to check the code for dev dependencies usage in production code. I tried looking for something like that but didn't came up with much.